# Read, then store, a prefix expression

Tags: c++, recursion, switch-statement, prefix, infix-notation

thanks for reading. I really need some help here. I'm faced with a problem that involves me using a recursive method to store a user-input fully marked prefix expression. In this particular instance, numbers are identified with the symbol "n", while symbols and such are just as they are. So, for example, this:

% 18 + 14 / ( 12 – 11 ) – 1183 % 17

Would be input into the command prompt as this:

- % n18 / n14 - n12 n11 % n1183 n17

Now, here's what I have for the processing of a completely parenthesized, infix, function. I have to create a method using similar fashion (inside of the same file, actually) and then work with it from there. I've already got the print function working, so I'm really just trying to get the storage to work now. Here's the code to read infix expressions:

```
Expr * readFPInfix(std::istream & infile)
{
    static std::string ops("*+/%-");
    char symbol;
    infile >> symbol;
    if (symbol == 'n')
    {
        long number;
        infile >> number;
        return new Atom(number);
    }
    else if (symbol == '(')
    {
        Expr * left = readFPInfix(infile);
        char op;
        infile >> op;
        if (ops.find(op) == std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "Unknown operator symbol '" << op << "'" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        Expr * right = readFPInfix(infile);
        infile >> symbol;
        // read the ending right parenthesis
        if (symbol != ')') {
            std::cout << "Invalid symbol '" << symbol << "':  ')' expected" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        switch (op)
        {
        case '*':
            return new Times(left, right);
        case '+':
            return new Plus(left, right);
        case '/':
            return new Divide(left, right);
        case '%':
            return new Mod(left, right);
        case '-':
            return new Subtract(left, right);
        default:
            std::cout << "Read error" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid symbol '" << symbol << "':  'n' or '(' expected" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm assuming we have to use the same stuff, so my main problem is reading the damned expression. I understand that in this method we're reading it symbol by symbol, then testing that symbol against prompts to test whether it's an operator or a number. Alright, cool. But how do I get left and right, so I can input it into something like Plus(left, right). I'm really struggling, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What does a "completely parenthesized, infix, function" have to do with evaluating prefix notation?

Comment: @EJP in my assignment, I was first tasked with writing out code for a fully parenthesized, infix expression first. I finished that because it had pretty detailed steps on how it was supposed to be done. Now I'm stuck with the prompt above and very little detail and need help. Does that make sense?

Comment: No. You finished one assignment: now you have another one. This one is a lot easier than the previous one, as you don't have to deal with precedence or parentheses.

Comment: But I don't understand how the processing works, which is why I'm seeking help. If you're not going to help, and instead, just post comments that don't point me in any sort of direction, then see yourself off from here.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question. The key issue is your assumption that you should reuse work. It's false. You should remove all irrelevant matter from your question. The process of evaluating infix is so easy it's trivial, you will find it everywhere. Try Wikipedia for example ... but surely you were taught it? and this is just an exercise in coding what you were taught? NB Being rude to people who are trying to help you isn't a rational strategy.

Comment: You're the one being rude, not me. I'm seeking help because I don't understand how the processing works on this type of problem. I've been taught the material yes, but this is conceptual, something that can't as easily be taught. I am struggling because I know I should use a switch and I know I should somehow store the operators/numbers as they come in. Do you have insight on this? @EJP

Comment: Forgive me if I seemed rude in the previous comments, I'm very stressed out as I have been working on this for over two weeks now and am stuck and the deadline is tomorrow morning at 12. @EJP