# Storing Prefix Expression (Recursive)

Tags: c++, recursion, expression, prefix

Thanks for reading. I really need some help here. I'm faced with a problem that involves me using a recursive method to store a user-input fully marked prefix expression. In this particular instance, numbers are identified with the symbol "n", while symbols and such are just as they are. So, for example, this:

% 18 + 14 / ( 12 – 11 ) – 1183 % 17

Would be input into the command prompt as this:

- % n18 / n14 - n12 n11 % n1183 n17

Now, earlier in the project, I was tasked with storing an infix expression but had a lot of help from already built code. So, here's what I have for the processing of a completely parenthesized, infix, function. I have to create a method using similar fashion (inside of the same file, actually) and then work with it from there. I've already got the print function working, so I'm really just trying to get the storage to work now. Here's the code to read infix expressions:

```
Expr * readFPInfix(std::istream & infile)
{
    static std::string ops("*+/%-");
    char symbol;
    infile >> symbol;
    if (symbol == 'n')
    {
        long number;
        infile >> number;
        return new Atom(number);
    }
    else if (symbol == '(')
    {
        Expr * left = readFPInfix(infile);
        char op;
        infile >> op;
        if (ops.find(op) == std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "Unknown operator symbol '" << op << "'" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        Expr * right = readFPInfix(infile);
        infile >> symbol;
        // read the ending right parenthesis
        if (symbol != ')') {
            std::cout << "Invalid symbol '" << symbol << "':  ')' expected" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        switch (op)
        {
        case '*':
            return new Times(left, right);
        case '+':
            return new Plus(left, right);
        case '/':
            return new Divide(left, right);
        case '%':
            return new Mod(left, right);
        case '-':
            return new Subtract(left, right);
        default:
            std::cout << "Read error" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid symbol '" << symbol << "':  'n' or '(' expected" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Now, I'm assuming we have to use the same stuff, so my main problem is reading the damned expression. I understand that in this method we're reading it symbol by symbol, then testing that symbol against prompts to test whether it's an operator or a number. Alright, cool. But how do I get left and right, so I can input it into something like Plus(left, right). I'm really struggling, so any help would be very appreciated.

NOTE: This is a homework assignment, so if someone gives me the answer then that is fine, or the pseudocode is fine too. Thank you.

Comment: Please correct your input.  I don't think that either of those is a legal prefix expression.  Each has 6 constants, which requires 5 operators.  The first expression has 6 operators; the second has 4.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: I was just using that input as an example. In reality, it should handle any prefix expression, I was just showing that the letter "n" goes before numbers as they are handled in the program. Other than that, it handles it as a normal prefix expression. @Prune

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Read, then store, a prefix expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513749/read-then-store-a-prefix-expression)

Comment: I never received a response and I don't know how to bump threads or anything like that so I reposted? @EJP

Answer (score 0):

Now ... as I've commented above, this is not a place where we simply hand you a design or coding.  However, I think I'm still within bounds to explain how infix breaks down into left and right operands.

There are only two types of operands in infix: a terminal (constant or variable) and an expression.

Every expression has the same form:

```
operator left-operand right-operand
```

As it turns out, you can easily parse a complex expression using these two rules: every time you hit an operator, you start a new expression (i.e. make a recursive call).  Let's step through a legal version of your given example:

```
% 18 + 14 / - 12 11 % 1183 17
```

The first thing we find is %; save the operator and go looking for the left and right operands in the remaining string, `18 + 14 / - 12 11 % 1183 17`.  The left is trivial; there's a constant right there.

```
// expression 1
operator = '%'
left = '18'
right = '+ 14 / - 12 11 % 1183 17'
```

This gives us the entire top-level expression.  However, we still have to parse the right operand.  It's another expression.  Stash the `+` as the operator and parse two operands.

Again, the left is trivial; the right is the rest of the expression:

```
// expression 2
operator = '+'
left = '14'
right = '/ - 12 11 % 1183 17'
```

Again, we still have to parse the right operand.  Stash the `/` as the operator, and ... ha!  This time, the left operand is an expression.  We still pass the entire string to the expression parser.

```
// expression 3
operator = '/'
left = <something from> '- 12 11 % 1183 17'
right = <on hold>
```

Here are the steps I've skipped over so far.  When we make the recursive call, we pass the entire expression.  The left-operand evaluation will eat whatever it needs, leaving the rest for the right evaluation.  Let's walk through this a little more carefully now ...

// expression 4
   operator = '-'
   left = 12
   right = 11
   remainder = '% 1183 17'

This remainder has to be passed back to the calling instance to use for the right operator.  Having found the left operand (and evaluated it to 1), we'll return to our parsing of expression 3:

```
// expression 3
operator = '/'
left = 1
right = '% 1183 17'
```

Now we likewise parse the right string, getting the value of 1183 % 17 or 10.  Note that I'm not walking us through this expression 5; like expression 4, it's a simple operation, ['%', 1183, 17].

Finally, we get to return to expression 3 and do 1 / 10 (integer arithmetic gives us 0 for this).  That 0 becomes the right side for expression 2, where we evaluate 14 + 0.  Finally, that result becomes the right side for expression 1, and the final answer is 18 % 14, or 4.

Now ... can you do the programming from there?